# How to display the ★ symbols in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, rtf

I have tried to create the RTF text from html when try this my html content have the text(★). In my RTF text has mentioned below,

```
string rtf = @"{\rtf1{\fonttbl{\f0\froman Times New Roman;}{\f1\fnil Arial;}}{\colortbl;\red238\green122\blue3;}{{\pard {\f1 \sl240\slmult1 {\b\fs24\par \qc \cf1 {XhtmlCells}\par}{\b\fs20\par \qc \cf1 {★★★✩✩}\par}{{XhtmlCells use the }{\b { RichTextBoxSupportsXHTML}}{ control from GotDotNet user samples to display XHTML formatted text inside a cell.}\par}}}}}";
```

I have tried to load this text in RichTextBox1.Rtf which will be shown the "?" instead of "★".

Can you please suggest me how to display this star symbol in RichTextBox.
Thanks in advance

Comment: richTextBox1.Font = new Font("Arial", 14);  
richTextBox1.Text = "Special character: U+2605";

Comment: @raBinn, I want to use the rtf format in richtextbox to display that star character.

Answer (score 3):

The parser will see the "Times New Roman" font at the beginning of your string and choke.

Try this one:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1031{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset1 Segoe UI Symbol;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.17134}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\f0\fs22\lang7\u9733?\f1\par
}
```

Seriously, it is probably a matter of font and character set.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
richTextBox1.Font = new Font("Arial", 14);  
richTextBox1.Text = "Special character: \u20ac";
```

Answer (score 0):

What .Net framework version are you targeting? I'm guessing something prior to 4.7.

What you're seeing is a limitation of the RichTextBox being based on RICHEDIT20W with versions prior to .Net 4.7. With the 4.7.x releases, the default switched to RICHEDIT50W.

Easiest solution is to just switch to a 4.7.x framework version, as long as that's an option. If you have to use an older framework for whatever reason, you can follow something like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311162/richtextbox-net-winforms-problem-or-alternative/1508545#1508545) (code copied below for posterity) to switch to the RICHEDIT50W editor. It's been around since the days of XP so it should be available pretty much everywhere anymore.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
       CreateParams cparams = base.CreateParams; 
       if (LoadLibrary("msftedit.dll") != IntPtr.Zero)
       {
          cparams.ClassName = "RICHEDIT50W";
       }
       return cparams;
     }
}
```

I have not used the above method, but what you're experiencing is a common issue. Searching for RichTextEdit, RICHEDIT20W, and/or RICHEDIT50W will get you far more than you've ever wanted to know about the internals of a rich text editor.